# -bash: /usr/local/bin/python: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, python-3.4, virtualenvwrapper

When I run `workon env1`,

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/python: No such file or directory
-bash: /usr/local/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

displays (the same line twice). However, I am in env1, as it shows up in my command prompt. When I run `which virtualenvwrapper.sh`, I get

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`

I saw another thread that said to run `ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh  /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` which gave me

```
ln: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: File exists
```

I installed the wrapper through `sudo -H pip install virtualenvwrapper`

Not really sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

For me, there was a link in `/usr/local/bin` to `python2`. I created another one, linking the same file to `python`.

```
$ cd /usr/local/bin

# The /usr/local/bin/python2 symlink exists already.
$ ls -al python2

lrwxr-xr-x 1 a_user a_group 37 Jul 26 09:54 /usr/local/bin/python2 -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.13_1/bin/python2

# Make a symlink for python. The path for the python2
# symlink on your system might be different from this
# example. Just use whatever path the python2 symlink
# is pointing to on your system.
$ ln -s ../Cellar/python/2.7.13_1/bin/python2 python

# Now the symlink exists at /usr/local/bin/python
$ ls -al python

lrwxr-xr-x 1 a_user a_group 37 Jul 26 14:29 python -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.13_1/bin/python2*
```

Comment: The fix is the same for Python 3. Just use the `/usr/local/bin/python3` symlink as the source for your path.